# how to match case in sensitive comparison in karate dsl 1.0.0

Tags: karate

Case in sensitive comparison with #regex is failing while upgrading to 1.0.0

Below code is working fine with karate 0.9.6

```
* def query = 'harry'
* match each $response.data.autoComplete == "#regex (?i).*" + query + ".*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in 1.0.1 https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v1.0.1

Please upgrade.